# Java project can display a new scene pretty easily, but only for certain JavaFXML files, how to fix this?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scene

Here's my code I'm struggling with (I marked the line that's giving me errors):

```
package sample.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.database.DBConnection;
import sample.model.User;

public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField loginEmail;

    @FXML
    private Button createAccountSwitchButton;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField loginPassword;

    private DBConnection dbConnection;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        dbConnection = new DBConnection();


        loginButton.setOnAction(event-> {
            String loginEmailText = loginEmail.getText().trim();
            String loginPasswordText = loginPassword.getText().trim();

            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(loginEmailText);
            user.setPassword(loginPasswordText);

            ResultSet userRow = dbConnection.checkForUser(user);
            int counter = 0;

            try{
                while (userRow.next()){
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter==1){
                    loginButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

//THE LINE BELOW THIS LINE-------------------------------------------------------------------

                    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/CreateAccount.fxml")); //THIS LINE

//THE LINE ABOVE THIS LINE-------------------------------------------------------------------
                    try {
                        loader.load();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Parent root = loader.getRoot();
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                    stage.showAndWait();

                }
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        //  Takes user to Create Account page
        createAccountSwitchButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            createAccountSwitchButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/CreateAccount.fxml"));

            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Parent root = loader.getRoot();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();

        });

    }

//    private void loginUser(String email, String password) {
//        //Checks if fields are empty, if so, bring them to user dashboard.
//        if(!email.equals("") || !password.equals("")){
//
//        }else{
//
//        }
//    }
}
```

At this point, it does exactly what I want it to do, it loads a new scene of "CreateAccount.fxml" file whenever I click the login button. But I want it to load a different FXML file, so I change the name to "Dashboard.fxml" which is my dashboard file name, but all of a sudden it no longer works and it's giving me errors that don't make any sense since my path is right and my name is right as well. This is what I changed that line to to throw the error below:

```
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/Dashboard.fxml"));
```

Lastly, to make sure, I created a completely new and blank FXML file and it won't load either.

Here are the full errors:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/andre/IdeaProjects/Covix/out/production/Covix/sample/view/Dashboard.fxml:12

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at sample.controller.LoginController.lambda$initialize$0(LoginController.java:68)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:215)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:633)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
    at sample.controller.CreateAccountController.lambda$initialize$0(CreateAccountController.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.view.Dashboard
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 106 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:336)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:194)
    at sample.controller.LoginController.lambda$initialize$0(LoginController.java:75)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:215)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:633)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
    at sample.controller.CreateAccountController.lambda$initialize$0(CreateAccountController.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
```

### Here's my Dashboard.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.view.Dashboard">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="-6.0" layoutY="-12.0" prefHeight="816.0" prefWidth="325.0" style="-fx-background-color: #001E8A;">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="46.0" layoutX="64.0" layoutY="60.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../assets/whiteLogo.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label layoutX="132.0" layoutY="55.0" text="Covix" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="43.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="5.0" layoutX="51.0" layoutY="155.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="222.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <TableView layoutX="379.0" layoutY="342.0" prefHeight="402.0" prefWidth="397.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Label layoutX="371.0" layoutY="30.0" text="Dashboard">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="44.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

### Here's my CreateAccount.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1050.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.CreateAccountController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="417.0" layoutY="-8.0" prefHeight="610.0" prefWidth="634.0" style="-fx-background-color: #001F8E;">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="378.0" fitWidth="534.0" layoutX="46.0" layoutY="118.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../assets/loginart.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label layoutX="247.0" layoutY="514.0" text="Stay Safe With Covix" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="16.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="160.0" layoutY="542.0" text="Update your scores and see other user's scores to keep yourself" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Label layoutX="160.0" layoutY="564.0" text="        and others around you as healthy and safe as possible." textFill="WHITE" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="606.0" prefWidth="417.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="44.0" fitWidth="44.0" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="39.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../assets/covixapplogo.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label layoutX="94.0" layoutY="40.0" text="Covix" textFill="#111111">
               <font>
                  <Font size="32.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="111.0" text="Create Account">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="27.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="42.0" layoutY="155.0" text="Get safer with your score. Create an account today!" textFill="#6c6c6c" />
            <Button fx:id="createAccountButton" layoutX="49.0" layoutY="480.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="313.0" style="-fx-background-color: #001F8E; -fx-border-radius: 10; -fx-border-color: none; text: white;" text="Create Account" textFill="WHITE" />
            <TextField fx:id="createAccountEmail" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="294.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="324.0" promptText="Email" />
            <Label layoutX="43.0" layoutY="265.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="235.0" text="Your email:" textFill="#191919">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="47.0" layoutY="337.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="235.0" text="Password:" textFill="#191919">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <CheckBox layoutX="55.0" layoutY="421.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="By creating an account you agree to the terms and conditions.">
               <font>
                  <Font size="10.0" />
               </font>
            </CheckBox>
            <Label layoutX="134.0" layoutY="531.0" text="Already have an account?" textFill="#6c6c6c" />
            <Button fx:id="loginButtonSwitch" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="549.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: none;" text="Log In" textFill="#041cf2">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <PasswordField fx:id="createAccountPassword" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="369.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="324.0" promptText="Password" />
            <TextField fx:id="createAccountFullName" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="218.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="324.0" promptText="e.g. John Doe" />
            <Label layoutX="42.0" layoutY="189.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="235.0" text="Your Full Name" textFill="#191919">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

So for some reason, my CreateAccount.fxml file loads, but not a completely new FXML file that's blank or my Dashboard.fxml file. I'm not sure what the problem could be. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I had to cut off like 15 lines of the error message (from the bottom) because I was past the 30K stackoverflow character limit, lemme know if you need them

Comment: Did you notice this line in the stack trace? `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.view.Dashboard`

Comment: @Abra yes I did, what does it mean?

Comment: Did you write a class named `Dashboard` in package `sample.view`?

Comment: @Abra yes I believe so, though I could be wrong, I'll update the post with a picture

Comment: @Abra updated with picture of folder structure. note that CreateAccount.fxml works but Dashboard doesnt and neither UserDash which is a blank file.

Comment: Where is file `Dashboard.java`?

Comment: @Abra doesn't exist, but CreateAccount.java doesn't exist either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229859/discussion-between-abra-and-psu-change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.view.Dashboard
```

This means that the FXML loader could not find a class named `Dashboard` in package `sample.view`.

The FXML loader looked for this class because that is what was written in file `Dashboard.fxml`, namely:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.view.Dashboard">
```

Notice the part at the end of the line:

```
fx:controller="sample.view.Dashboard"
```

If you don't need a controller class then simply remove that part.